# Suppose $f$ holomorphic and its image is a subset of the unit circle. Then show f is constant.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, solution-verification, mobius-transformation

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 3.8

> Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in region $G$, and $f(G) \subseteq \{ |z|=1 \}$. Prove $f$ is constant.

(I guess we may assume $f: G \to \mathbb C$ s.t. image(f)=$f(G)$. I guess it doesn't matter if we somehow have $f: A \to \mathbb C$ for any $A$ s.t. $G \subseteq A \subseteq \mathbb C$ as long as $G$ is a region and $f$ is holo there.)

I will now attempt to elaborate the following proof at a [Winter 2017 course in Oregon State University](https://math.oregonstate.edu/%7Edeleenhp/teaching/winter17/MTH483/hw2-sol.pdf).

**Question 1**: For the following elaboration of the proof, what errors if any are there?

**Question 2**: Are there more elegant ways to approach this? I have a feeling this can be answered with Ch2 only, i.e. Cauchy-Riemann or differentiation/holomorphic properties instead of having to use Möbius transformations.

> OSU Pf (slightly paraphrased): Let $g(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$, and define $h(z)=g(f(z)), z \in G \setminus \{z : f(z) = 1\}$. Then $h$ is holomorphic on its domain, and $h$ is imaginary valued by Exer 3.7. By a variation of Exer 2.19, $h$ is constant. QED

My (elaboration of OSU) Pf: $\because f(G) \subseteq C[0,1]$, let's consider the Möbius transformation in the preceding Exer 3.7 $g: \mathbb C \setminus \{z = 1\} \to \mathbb C$ s.t. $g(z) := \frac{1+z}{1-z}$:

If we plug in $C[0,1] \setminus \{1\}$ in $g$, then we'll get the imaginary axis by Exer 3.7. Precisely: $$g(\{e^{it}\}_{t \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}}) = \{is\}_{s \in \mathbb R}. \tag{1}$$ Now, define $G' := G \setminus \{z \in G | f(z) = 1 \}$ and $h: G' \to \mathbb C$ s.t. $h := g \circ f$ s.t. $h(z) = \frac{1+f(z)}{1-f(z)}$. If we plug in $G'$ in $h$, then we'll get the imaginary axis. Precisely: $$h(G') := \frac{1+f(G')}{1-f(G')} \stackrel{(1)}{=} \{is\}_{s \in \mathbb R}. \tag{2}$$

Now Exer 2.19 says that a real valued holomorphic function over a region is constant: $f(z)=u(z) \implies u_x=0=u_y \implies f'=0$ to conclude by Thm 2.17 that $f$ is constant or simply by partial integration that $u$ is constant. Actually, an imaginary valued holomorphic function over a region is constant too: $f(z)=iv(z) \implies v_x=0=v_y \implies f'=0$ again by Cauchy-Riemann Thm 2.13 to conclude by Thm 2.17 that $f$ is constant or simply by partial integration that $v$ is constant.

$(2)$ precisely says that $h$ is imaginary valued over $G'$. $\therefore,$ if $G'$ is a region (A) and if $h$ is holomorphic on $G'$ (B), then $h$ is constant on $G'$ with value I'll denote $Hi, H \in \mathbb R$:

$\forall z \in G',$

$$Hi = \frac{1+f(z)}{1-f(z)} \implies f(z) = \frac{Hi-1}{Hi+1}, \tag{3}$$

where $Hi+1 \ne 0 \forall H \in \mathbb R$.

$\therefore, f$ is constant on $G'$ (Q4) with value given in $(3)$.

QED except possibly for (C)

---

> (A) $G'$ is a region

I guess if $G \setminus G'$ is finite, then G' is a region. I'm thinking $D[0,1]$ is a region and then $D[0,1] \setminus \{0\}$ is still a region.

> (B) To show $h$ is holomorphic in $G'$:

Well $h(z)$ is differentiable $\forall z \in G'$ and $f(z) \ne 1 \forall z \in G'$ and $f'(z)$ exists in $G' \subseteq G$ because $f$ is differentiable in $G$ because $f$ is holomorphic in $G$.

$$h'(z) = g'(f(z)) f'(z) = \frac{2}{(1-w)^2}|_{w=f(z)} f'(z) = \frac{2 f'(z)}{(1-f(z))^2} $$

Now, $f'(z)$ exists on an open disc $D[z,r_z] \ \forall z \in G$ where $r_z$ denotes the radius of the open disc s.t. $f(z)$ is holomorphic at $z$. So, I guess $\frac{2 f'(z)}{(1-f(z))^2} = h'(z)$ exists on an open disc with the same radius $D[z,r_z] \ \forall z \in G'$, and $\therefore, h$ is holomorphic in $G'$.

> (C) Possible flaw:

It seems that on $G'$, $f$ has value $\frac{Hi-1}{Hi+1}$ while on $G \setminus G'$, $f$ has value $1$.

$$\therefore, \forall z \in G, f(z) = \frac{Hi-1}{Hi+1} 1_{G'}(z) + 1_{G \setminus G'}(z)$$

It seems then that we've actually show only that $f$ is constant on $G$ except for the subset of G where $f=1$.

Comment: This is all very complicated: "to show $h$ is holomorphic in $G'$?". Why not just appeal to the fact that the composite of two holomorphic functions is holomorphic?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Not sure that's in [the text](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html). Is it please?

Comment: If it's not, then so much the worse for that text.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ayt thanks. Is Möbius how you would approach this?

Comment: I'd use the open mapping theorem.... A more naive way is to apply Cauchy-Riemann.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks. Re Cauchy-Riemann: is used in employing Exer 2.19 and its variant. What did you have in mind? Re open mapping: MAAANNN. The proof uses Rouché's theorem, a topic in Ch9 in the text while this exer is still Ch3

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown i added a paragraph....is my post less complicated or unclear now please?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown edited question w/c is now reopened.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(G) \subseteq \{ z=1 \}$?

Comment: @zhw. Image of G under f is a susbet of the unit circle

Comment: But you wrote $z=1$ not $|z|=1$

Comment: @zhw. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: @XanderHenderson 'Please point out any errors.'

Comment: @XanderHenderson Good question. My answer: 'Suddenly, I no longer care about the kinda inelegant Möbius approach. Thanks! '

Comment: @XanderHenderson Edited!

Comment: I agree with @AnginaSeng's comment: a direct application of the open-mapping Theorem for holomorphic functions gives the result. I find it really, really ackward that the mentioned courses use Rouché's Theorem to prove the open mapping Theorem while it can be shown really early in complex analysis thanks to analytic series, that are a direct consequence of Cauchy's formula.

Comment: @Didier actually, i don't think open mapping theorem is proved or even stated in the text. (i forgot. and i didn't check now) however i believe what i was referring to before was [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)#Proof). i guess i just looked it up on wiki. actually even now i don't think i've encountered open mapping theorem for regular $\mathbb C$, but i learned open mapping theorem when learning about riemann surfaces. (just the statement not the proof lol)

Comment: @Didier 1 - 'hile it can be shown really early in complex analysis' --> well it's the same principle as the concept of anti-holomorphic right? (see my answer)

Comment: @Didier 2 - anyhoo may you please provide open mapping theorem proof for just cauchy's differentiation formula?

Comment: @AnginaSeng ok i'll try proving with open mapping theorem. i'll post as answer... wait...oh wait that sounds pretty easy. lol. but kinda overkill? i mean...sure it's pretty easy when you use open mapping, but it sounds like using too high machinery. like using functional analysis to prove the pythagorean theorem

Comment: @Didier 3 - wait open mapping theorem is kinda overkill? i mean...sure it's pretty easy when you use open mapping, but it sounds like using too high machinery. like using functional analysis to prove the pythagorean theorem

Comment: @Didier  4 - wait there's no integration at this point of the text as i recall....so open mapping theorem's out?

Comment: @AnginaSeng ok re comp of holo is holo, i posted an answer. lemme know what you think please

Comment: @Didier i posted 3 answers. lemme know what you think please

Comment: @AnginaSeng  a weird thought i didn't quite analyse. what if $G$ were open but not connected? i believe the conclusion is slightly different (constant on each connected component or something), but is open mapping theorem the way to go about this? i'd think zhw.'s answer is how to go about this. (which is similar to my answer about the anti-holomorphic).

Comment: @Didier 5 - a weird thought i didn't quite analyse. what if $G$ were open but not connected? i believe the conclusion is slightly different (constant on each connected component or something), but is open mapping theorem the way to go about this? i'd think zhw.'s answer is how to go about this. (which is similar to my answer about the anti-holomorphic).

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f\overline {f}=1$ in $G.$ This implies $\overline {f} =1/f$ in $G.$ Hence $\overline {f}$ is holomorphic in $G.$ This implies both $f+\overline f= 2\text { Re } f$ and $f-\overline f=2i\text { Im } f$ are holomorphic in $G.$ By the remarks you made right after $(2)$ in your question, these functions are constant, which implies $f$ is constant.

Comment: I just knew there had to be a way to do this with just regular differentiation/holomorphic stuff and not Möbius. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I changed your edit as that page is not what I would refer a reader to. I was referring to the remarks in your question right after $(2);$ no need for anything else.

Comment: 1 - not sure why i didn't accept this as answer before. 2 - not sure why i ever linked to exer 2.16. maybe i just got exer 2.16 and exer 2.19 mixed up.

Comment: zhw. i posted [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4105658) just now. it's like yours but without wheel reinventions but i use the term 'anti-holomorphic' . what do you think of [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4105658) please?

Answer (score 7):

The Cauchy-Riemann equations have a geometric interpretation. Let $f$
be holomorphic at $a$ and let $f'(a)\ne0$. Consider the horizontal
line through $a$ consisting of points $a+s$ for real $s$, and
also the vertical line through $a$, that is the points $a+it$ for
$t$ real.
Then these are mapped by $f$ into two curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ meeting
at $f(a)$. Cauchy-Riemann implies these meet at right angles there.

But if the image of $f$ were within a 1-dimensional subspace such as
the unit circle, then $C_1$ and $C_2$ would be restricted within
too, which means they cannot intersect orthogonally.  The only
way out of this impasse is for $f'(a)=0$. This must happen for all $a$.

An introductory book that makes much of such geometric interpretations
is Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis* (OUP).

If you really don't like geometry, write $f(x+iy)=u+iv$ in the usual
way. If $f$ maps to the unit circle, then $u^2+v^2=1$. Differentiating
gives $uu_x+vv_x=uu_y+vv_y=0$. Cauchy-Riemann gives
$-uv_x+vu_x=0$. Then
$$u_x=u^2u_x+v^2u_x=u(uu_x+vv_x)+v(-uv_x+vu_x)=0$$
and similarly $v_x=0$. Therefore $f'=0$.

Comment: I just knew there had to be a way to do this with just Cauchy-Riemann. Suddenly, I no longer care about the kinda inelegant Möbius approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another fun way is to use Parseval's identity (one should never pass up an opportunity to do so). Suppose your region contains $0$ (if not, just translate it so that it does). Then $f$ has a power series representation $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ which converges near $0$, and for $r$ sufficiently small we have

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})|^2 d\theta = \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2 r^{2n}.
$$

Our assumptions imply that the left side is equal to $1$ for all such $r$, but the only way the right can be constant is if $a_n=0$ for $n \geq 1$. I guess this just shows that $f$ is locally constant, but then the derivative is $0$ at every point in $G$, and this means $G$ is globally constant.

Comment: haha Fourier series niiice. can't upvote right now, but i will even if i don't really understand all this

Comment: However see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4105872/3

Comment: oh wait wait i see it. assuming the assumptions indeed imply such we get $f=a_0 \in \mathbb C$ and then $|a_0|^2=1$, w/c is exactly what it means that image of $f$ is a subset of the unit circle (i.e. image of $f$ is a set consisting of a point on the unit circle). looked it up on wiki further. looks really fun. nice.

Answer (score 0):

In every point on a line in the plane the possible tangent vectors form a real monodimensional vector space. An holomorphic function has in every point of its domain a derivative map that is a complex linear, that is a roto-homothetic real transformation of the plane.

Turning attention to your problem: in every point of the region $G$ the tangent vectors form a bidimensional real vector space. When a tangent vector is transformed by the derivative map it is rotated and/or enlarged in the plane of the tangent vectors in the image of the point. But the only possible tangent vectors in any point of the image (subset of the unit circle, that is a set of arcs and/or points) are in a real monodimensional vector space (for points on an arc) or zero-dimensional vector space (for isolated points). So for that roto-homothetic transformation to be fitted, it must make any tangent vector in the region $G$ vanish, that is, the derivative map must be $0$.

Comment: HWAT. At this point, the reader is only 3 chapters into complex analysis and is not expected to have a topology background apart from basic topology in elementary analysis. Anyhoo, my understanding of your answer is...that that's your best (as in most elementary proof you can think of) guess for Q5, and you're not answering Q1-4?

Comment: trying, edited question w/c is now reopened.

Answer (score 0):

After discovering the term anti-holomorphic, I have an answer similar to zhw.'s: It starts the same but then doesn't reinvent the wheel or something:

> If $f: G \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic on $G$ and anti-holomorphic on $G$, then $f$ is constant on $G$. $\tag{*}$

We have $|f|=1$ on $G$ iff $f \overline f = 1$  on $G$. Then just as in zhw.'s answer, $\overline f$ is holomorphic in $G$ i.e. $f$ is anti-holomorphic on $G$. Therefore, $f$ is constant on $G$.

Now, the non-wheel reinvention here is that the way one proves $(*)$ in the 1st place is what zhw. said. So yeah this exercise seems pretty easy if you know the concept of anti-holomorphic. It's not so advanced to teach an elementary complex analysis student, but maybe it's not something you'd teach an elementary complex analysis student.

Answer (score 0):

i guess [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)), as suggested by Angina Seng, is [inadmissible](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/116019), but anyhoo

$f$ is either constant or non-constant. If constant, then done. If non-constant, then by open mapping theorem, $f$ is open. Then $G$ is open implies $f(G)$ open (in $\mathbb  C$). However no non-empty subset of the unit circle is open (in $\mathbb C$).

remarks:

1. so it seems pretty easy with open mapping theorem, but the proof for open mapping theorem seems to use either Rouché's theorem or cauchy's differentiation formula, sooo...yeah. too high at this point of the text.
2. seems kinda overkill to use open mapping. it's like using functional analysis to prove pythagorean theorem.

- Update: Trivia: [Parseval's identity is a generalisation of pythaogrean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity). There's a [new answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4111029) that uses Parseval's identity.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.5648.pdf) provides an elementary proof of the open mapping theorem for holomorphic function, which does not use anything else but the fact an holomorphic function has everywhere a converging Taylor series, which is a direct consequence of Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: @Didier but there isn't any cauchy's differentiation formula at this point in the book right?

Comment: I just read the table of contents of the book you provided. The fact is I would not teach complex analysis in this order. In my opinion, Cauchy's integral formula is the most important thing to get in complex analysis: (again, in my opinion) **everything** rely on it.

Comment: oh wow thank you for saying this. i really did find parts of ch3 weird or out of order

Comment: @Didier 1 - wait which part would you teach cauchy's differentiation/integral formulation? surely it must be at least after chapter 2?

Comment: @Didier 2 - wait just because it's in this particular order in the book doesn't mean that's how they actually teach elementary complex analysis right? i mean, loring tu, michael artin and james munkres don't teach their books (or even necessarily recommend that their books be read) in order of the chapters right?

Comment: I don't know in which order they teach their courses, they weren't my professors. Also, I did not say their teachning is absurd. In the book, Cauchy's integral formula appears in chapter 4, while the first three chapters are just preliminaries: it seems they are actually OK with the fact Cauchy's integral formula is one of the very first result to state in such a course.

Comment: @Didier you said 'The fact is I would not teach complex analysis in this order. In my opinion, Cauchy's integral formula is the most important thing to get in complex analysis:' --> ok so what would you do differently besides possibly moving some of the mobius stuff to later on?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea that uses a weaker version of the open mapping theorem:

- if $f$ is constant, then there is nothing to prove
- if $f$ is non-constant, $f'$ is not identically zero: let $z_0$ such that $f'(z_0) \neq 0$. By the inverse function theorem, there exists an open neighbourhood of $z_0$, say $V$, such that $f(V)$ is open and $f : V \to f(V)$ is bijective with smooth inverse. Hence $f(V) \subset \mathrm{Im}(f)$, and the image of $f$ contains an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$: it cannot fit in the circle, which has empty interior.

Comment: thanks can't upvote now since limit. 1 - why change not to non?

Comment: 2 - 'local diffeomorphism' --> eh topology/geometry stuff. advanced for this course?

Comment: If you do not like the term "local diffeomorphism", just focus on the term "inverse function theorem", which is not too avanced for this course. In fact, I don't expect students to understand complex analysis if they do not know a bit of multivariable real analysis.

Comment: yeah inverse function theorem....the one about how a smooth map of smooth manifolds of equal dimension is locally invertible at a point iff the differential at the point is an isomorphism...kidding. yeah the elementary one. wait so what's local diffeomorphism here? locally...invertible and both $f$ and $f^{\text{local inverse}}$ are...what, real-smooth? complex-smooth? holomorphic?

Comment: Don't be so sarcastic. There is no need to talk about manifolds, just about functions between open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and in fact, here, of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The only theorem to prove is that if $f : U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth and if $\mathrm{d}f(x_0)$ is invertible as a linear map (elementary linear algebra though), then there exists an open subset $V$ containing $x_0$ such that $f(V)$ is open and  $f : V \to f(V)$ is a bijection with smooth inverse.

Comment: Moreover, the only relevant information here for the proof I stated is that $f(V)$ is open. No need to talk about diffeomorphism in fact.

Comment: Didier how was it sarcasm when i said 'kidding' ? the comment should be viewed as a joke not sarcasm...i think

Comment: anyway ok so now we are viewing holo $f=f(z)$ as smooth $f=f(x,y)$ in order to apply inverse function theorem? p.s. i'm actually not so familiar with inverse function theorem pre-manifolds. maybe i didn't make this so clear in earlier comment and this is why my humour was lost...